# Подружить Dagger с Koin

Tags: android, dagger, koin

В проекте столкнулся с такой проблемой: подключенная библиотека к проекту, использует **dagger**, но в основном проекте во всю начал использовать **koin**. Столкнулся с проблемой как вытянуть объекты из библиотеки. Если какой то бесшовный способ соединить **koin**  и **dagger**?